# Подтверждение обработки персональных данных

Tags: веб-программирование, юридические-аспекты, персональные-данные

Сейчас по закону нужно на каждой форме (которая собирает личные данные) запрашивать у пользователя подтверждение на обработку данных. С точки зрения закона можно ли сделать эту галочку сразу выбранной? На всех сайта сделано по разному. Есть мнение что каждое обязательно поле уменьшает конверсию, поэтому планирую ставить галочку уже выбранную. Может кто знает, не нарушает ли это закон?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В таком случае нужно составить текст в котором будет написано чтото типа: " Вы принимаете политику сайта , согласны с тем что: "бла-бла-бла"  и тд. Тп. Если согласны-
То нажмите галку и перейдите. Или вообще " Переходя по данной ссылке вы соглашаетесь с "бла-бла-бла".

Comment: у вас есть какая-нибудь ссылка на документ который это регулирует?

Comment: Вот с этим как раз и загвоздка. Все так делают но никто не может ответить как:

Comment: 1) как можно доказать что именно условный Иван Иванович нажал на ссылку а не его сосед сидящий рядом с ним без его согласия(подписи то нет). 2) как по законодательству должно выглядеть юридически правильно оформленное соглашение не нарушающее чьих либо прав (ведь в сети как правило копи-паст рулит). 3) даже если Вам кто-то посоветует какую-то ссылку - не факт что эта статья не имеет никаких поправок или не отменяется другим каким-то юр.доком, или окажется общим описанием которое не раскрывает всей сути.

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman Я не юрист, но с образованием бугалтера в прошлом,  и понимаю что если идет речь о соблюдении всех норм,  и попахивает риском разбирательства - нужно идти к юристу.  Из энного количества  членов сообщества - точно кто-то имеет юр-образование. Но,  насколько оно актуально если человек не практикует? А если и практикует - то какова вероятность что именно в этой области? Будет ли чей то частный случай полностью соответствовать Вашему частному случаю?